# django apache configuration confusing.

Tags: django, apache2, django-admin

I m new to django. I run the server like

```
python manage.py runserver.
```

Now i would like to get it integrated with Apache server for my production machine. 
I am not denying that tutorial is not available in the website. But i feel it is too much scattered, and i am afraid if i have missed any link which provides list of commands to be executed.

It would be a gr8 help if someone points of the list, along with what i did the below.

```
* Installed django
* installed libapache2-mod-wsgi, through apt-get install.
```

I am confused what to be done next.

I am using ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Why Down voting?.. I just asked a question, which i could not able to figure out.

Comment: Have you read Django's [Apache deployment docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)? You should do so, follow them, then ask a *specific* question if you are having problems.

Comment: python manage.py runserver is only the development server for your convinience. You should NOT use it for production purposes. Refer to Daniel´s link for further help on apache deployment.

Comment: Thanks, and i am reading that. I trying in my local machine only. What i do not understand is what is mysite.com?. can it be simply a directory?

Answer (score 0):

mysite.com in Django's tutorial is actually just a directory. But you will need later to indicate this directory in your Apache/nginx/whatever settings (virtualhost settings) - so it easy quite convenient to name directory with domain name.